# How to add SwitchPreference above a ListView in PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-preferences

I have a custom preference which extends `PreferenceFragment`.
By default `PreferenceFragment` has an internal `ListView`. You can check its default layout here:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/preference_list_fragment.xml

This internal `ListView` is enough for me. So I just call

```
ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

then fill the `ListView` with my data.

Note that **I do not need to call** this function `addPreferencesFromResource`.

But now I want to add a `SwitchPreference` above my `ListView`. 
Please help me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in `PreferenceFragment`.

```
PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen();
SwitchPreference switchPreference = new SwitchPreference(context);

// Assign value to switchPreference

screen.addPreference(switchPreference)
```

Comment: `getPreferenceScreen()` returns `null`. Because I do not call `addPreferencesFromResource`

Comment: @TOP then how you're adding other preferences ?